# How to use single class to open multiple webview

Tags: android, class, webview, uiwebview

I am making an app which have 20+ web view in it. So it is not practical to create 20+ class and its 20+ activities... Because it's going to make app more complex.
Is there any way from that I can store all links to strings.xml or in array. and when I press a specific button then it open a specific link from string. Xml and open to web view..

Answer (score 4):

take a string array like below

```
String[] website = { "http://edmontoncentennial.com/",
            "http://rdroofingltd.com/", "http://millwoodsauto.ca/",
            "http://erbc.ca/"};
```

whenever you click on a view pass link as parameter to setWeb(array[positio]);

```
public void setWeb(String link){
         WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
         webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
         webView.loadUrl(link);

}
```